# React Native Expo : There is no fontmanager in module registry

Tags: expo

[Error Log Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWLtv.png)

Error: There is no FontManager in module registry. Are you sure all the dependencies of expo-font are installed or linked.

I cannot find any message from google. Anyone can help me?